# How to get the index of the selected item from a dropdown in ReactJs and material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

This is the component for Dropdown:

```
<DropDownField
  name={formElement.name}
  label={formElement.name}
  value={formik.values[formElement.name] || ''}                     
  dropDownItems={formElement.name === 'Loan Details' ? loanEnum : formElement.enum}
  className={classes.flexGrow}
  onChange={dropDownChangeHandler}
  error={formik.touched[formElement.name] && Boolean(formik.errors[formElement.name])}
  helperText={formik.touched[formElement.name] && formik.errors[formElement.name]}
 />
```

and the `DropDownField` component:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
        {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
        <InputLabel id="simple-select-label">{props.label}</InputLabel>
        <Select labelId="simple-select-label" id="simple-select" {...props}>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line */}
            {props.dropDownItems.map((element, index) => (
                <MenuItem key={element + index} value={element}>
                    {element}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
</FormControl>
```

`onChange` function:

```
const dropDownChangeHandler = async (e) => {
        const loanDetails = await LoanDetailsService.search(formik.values['Employee Number']);
        formik.handleChange(e);
        console.log(loanDetails);
        formik.setFieldValue('Loan Type', loanDetails[index]['Loan Type']);
    };
```

Now in the `onChange` function how do i get the index of the dropdown items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try adding a data attribute to your menu items, e.g.:

```
{props.dropDownItems.map((element, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={element + index} value={element} data-index={index}>
        {element}
    </MenuItem>
))}
```

And then getting that index from `e.currentTarget.dataset.index` or by grabbing the second argument (child) sent to the event handler as detailed in the onChange section on [this page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/).

e.g. something like:

```
const dropDownChangeHandler = async (e) => {
    const index = +e.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    const loanDetails = await LoanDetailsService.search(formik.values['Employee Number']);
    formik.handleChange(e);
    console.log(loanDetails);
    formik.setFieldValue('Loan Type', loanDetails[index]['Loan Type']);
};
```

or

```
const dropDownChangeHandler = async (e, child) => {
    const index = child.props['data-index'];
    const loanDetails = await LoanDetailsService.search(formik.values['Employee Number']);
    formik.handleChange(e);
    console.log(loanDetails);
    formik.setFieldValue('Loan Type', loanDetails[index]['Loan Type']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over the elements, the map method gives you the indices of the element, you could bubble the index of the given selected element via handler using the onClick prop

```
{props.dropDownItems.map((element, index) => (
<MenuItem key={element + index} value={element} onClick={()=> handleItemClick(index)} > 
{element}
</MenuItem> 
))}
```

The **handleItemClick** code will be as in the following

```
const handleItemClick = (idx) => {
console.log(idx); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way? because the `onChange`  of dropdown field and `onclick` function of dropdown item happen during the same render, thus my state variable doesnt store the desired value

Comment: I can't see where exactly the onChange in your dropdownField component is triggered?

Comment: I edited the post and added the function, now `onClick` sets the index of a menu item and `onChange` which requires the index, happens at the same time, so the index still shows its previous state as its still in the same render, state will update only on the next render.